# How can I make a white rectangle extend all the way down, on top of another background?

Tags: html, css, background

I'm a complete beginner. I tried my best to search for a solution, but part of the problem is that I don't even know what the technical term is for the thing I'm trying to do.

Essentially I want to have a tiled background repeating everywhere, but then also have a white rectangle that extends from the top of the page to the bottom, occupying roughly 50% of the horizontal screen space. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you might just want a repeated background of the page and then absolutely-positioned `<div>` with white background.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic stuff, I suggest you take a beginner's course in HTML and CSS before going too much further.

```
body {background: url(tile.png) left top repeat;}

content {background-color: #fff; margin: 0px auto; width: 50%;}
```

Comment: I didn't upvote your solution just because of one detail: the content container does not extend to the bottom of the page, as per requested. Otherwise it's a legitimate approach.

Comment: I've never had any success with height=100%. I generally use other methods, such as <br style="clear:both;"/> at the end of the content.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Here's a solution that uses only the `background` CSS property applied to document body, no extra elements needed. It's documented so you can understand whats going on.

```
body
{
    /*
    * This specifies two background images, separated by comma
    * First parameter is just a white pixel
    * For the second use any background pattern of your choice
    */
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/qdx0kzd.png"),  
    url("http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/tasky_pattern.png");

    /*Center background images, self-explanatory*/
    background-position: center;
    /*Repeat white background image on Y-axis (vertical) only*/
    background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat;
    /*Make white background size 50%. Adjust as needed*/
    background-size: 50%, auto;
}
```

You can see an example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dV2zZ/6/

**Solution 2**

This solution applies different backgrounds to different elements: the pattern to the document body, and the white background to a content container. Code is also documented for better understanding.

HTML

```
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0;

    /* Make document size extend to the bottom of the page */
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    /*Patern background. Use a pattern of your choice*/
    background-image: url("http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/tasky_pattern.png");
}

#content
{
    /*Make container background white*/
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*Center container*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*Size 50%, adjust as needed*/
    width: 50%;
    /*Extend to the bottom*/
    height: 100%;
}
```

See an example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jDRG3/1/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you wanted. It is a tiled, repeating background with a white strip, half the screen space, going down the middle. If you want a tiled background, you don't need to define anything in CSS, and CSS will do it for you, but I'm not sure with the browser compatibility so it might be safer to explicitly define `repeat:`.

First of all, to those complaining that `height: 100%` does not work, note that the div with `height: 100%` is only being the `height: 100%` of its **parent element** (the container that encloses the div, in the case of this JSFiddle, the `#container`). Therefore, if its parent has no content, the div with 100% height will become invisible.

Therefore, the `html`, `body` and `container` must all have `height: 100%` for the white strip to have 100% height here in this JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDDn4/21/)

After this you are free to add any content to the white strip, which will probably be your webpage! :D

**Note:** Here I have defined the strip as `width: 50%;` but sometimes it may be better to explicitly define the width (`width: 1200px;`) so that you can avoid problems with the text and divs going haywire when you zoom in, zoom out, etc.

**Edit:**
Also, since the height of the container increases as you add more content, such as divs, the problem with the white strip not reaching the bottom of the page is that you simply have nothing that fills it up. As you add more content the strip will naturally grow to fill the page. Good luck!

Comment: Hello,

You haven't replied; did you solve your problem, or are you still working on it?

If you solved it, please tell us why, I'm looking for alternate solutions too ;)